# Get wordpress user metadata with custom function in external script in same server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have wordpress and script "B" installed in the same server. In script "B", I am trying to pull a user metadata from wordpress database so it can be displayed. I have the script below, but for some reason the foreach is not outputing nothing. I tested the query in phpmyadmin and it returns the rows, but, again, the foreach is not outputing nothing when I do it in the script. $mydb was initialized a few rows above. Please help. Thank you!

```
$query = "
        SELECT wp_users.ID AS id_1, wp_users.user_login AS username, wp_usermeta.user_id AS id_2, wp_usermeta.meta_key AS metakey, wp_usermeta.meta_value AS metavalue
        FROM wp_users
        LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta 
        ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
        WHERE wp_users.user_login = '" . $username. "'
    ";

    $results = $mydb->get_results( $query );
    foreach ( $results as $result ) 
    {
        echo $result->metavalue."<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r( $result );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

You will see what is inside the *$result*.